# How to alter a table to make a combination of fields as the primary key in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I created a table named mytable1 in MySQL with 4 fields namely col1, col2, col3, col4,. Initially while creating the table I made col1 the primary key. But now I need to make the combination of (col1, col2,col3) as the primary key as col1's value need to repeat in my table.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable1 DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2, col3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to drop first the primary since you can only have one primary in a table and add it again. This can be done in a single line,

```
ALTER TABLE  tableName DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2, col3)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbe2f/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable1
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2, col3);
```